# Pytube module is giving "streamingData" error

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\My All Study Work\Youtube Downloader\YT Download With Index.py", line 14, in <module>
    Download(link)
  File "e:\My All Study Work\Youtube Downloader\YT Download With Index.py", line 5, in Download
    youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 161, in streaming_data
    return self.vid_info['streamingData']
```

Code is :

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("Enter link :")
YT=YouTube(link)
YT.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
print("Successfull")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `YouTube(link)` with `YouTube(link,use_oauth=True,allow_oauth_cache=True)`

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("Enter link:")
YT=YouTube(link, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
YT.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
print("Successfull")
```